# Use VBA Macro to Save each Excel Worksheet as Separate Workbook with a introductory tab

Tags: excel, vba, split, copy, addition

I have a spreadsheet with lots of tabs.  I am wanting to copy each tab into its own file which I can do with the code below.

My problem is adding an instruction sheet aswell to each of the new workbooks.  I have an instruction sheet in the original workbook.

Your help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Splitbook()
MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
sht.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
Filename:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name & " SP Signoff.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? It should be simple to just do something like this psuedocode, `Workbooks("Original.xls").Worksheets("Instructions").Copy Workbooks("NewWorkbook")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Splitbook()

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
    Dim strPath As String

    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = Sheets("Instructions")

    strPath = wkb.Path

    For Each sht In wkb.Sheets
        If sht.Name <> "Instructions" Then
            sht.Copy

            With ActiveSheet
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            End With

            wks.Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
            Filename:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name & " SP Signoff.xlsx"
            ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works great when followingthe steps, although it becomes stuck on the SaveAs stage.  Think it’s because it maybe on the Wong sheet, ie instructions sheet ?

Comment: All sorted....  Combined the 2 versions to produce the one below.  The problem was to do with the Path it was saving to.  The code below works perfectly....  Thanks for all your help....

Comment: Sub Splitbook()

Dim wrb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet

Set Wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set wks = Sheets("Instructions")

MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
sht.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
wks.Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
Filename:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name & " SP Signoff.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next sht
End Sub